# Linq and lambda, both neglects the identity colum when I perform basic operations - how to avoid it?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a DataTable, say:

```
OrdersDataTable dtResults = Datalayer.Orders.GetOrdersByCustomer(1)
```

and then I am trying to select a part of that to tie to a data repeater like so

```
var CustomerOrdersByProduct = dtResults.Where(r => r.ProductId == ProductId);
               // OR
var CustomerOrdersByProduct = from r in dtResults
                              where r.ProductId == ProductId
                              select r

rpOrders.DataSource = CustomerOrdersByProduct;
rpOrders.DataBind();
```

and the stored procedure, returns a table like this:

```
OrderId    ProductId    CustomerId .....(etc)
```

But I get an error when  I try to access `OrderId` (which is the primary key) in my `var CustomerOrdersByProduct`, even when debugging, or in just intellisense.. What am I missing please?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your `OrdersDataTable`'s row type doesn't have an `OrderId` property, even though the stored procedure is returning it.

Look at the design for `OrdersDataTable`, which I assume is a generated strongly-typed datatable. Perhaps you've mapped it to an `Id` property instead of `OrderId`, or something like that? Either way, I very much doubt that this is anything to do with LINQ directly.

Comment: Hi Jon! You are right, my OrdersDataTable is actually strongly typed to something completely different, I am just reusing that because I already have the data and want to avoid another data access, esp. when I already have the data.. so the table adapter is really not orders table adapter.. but still, is there a way to access OrderId ?

Comment: @LocustHorde: Not if your OrdersDataTable doesn't expose it. Whenever you start reusing something which is designed for "something completely different" you should work out whether it's really a good idea. I suggest that your OrdersDataTable probably *should* expose the order ID though...

Comment: okay I feel stupid now, I re-configured the table adapter and it automatically added the wanted column. D'oh. Thanks very much for pointing me in the right direction though!